# Generating CSS media queries with javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, media-queries

Is it possible to create full media query rules on the fly using Javascript or jQuery?

I've used numerous media queries to target generalised viewports and specific devices/screens using inline CSS, imports and linked files:

```
@media screen and (min-width:400px) { ... }
@import url(foo.css) (min-width:400px);
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 400px)" href="foo.css" />
```

I can add/remove classes using jQuery:

```
$("foobar").click(function(){
  $("h1,h2,h3").addClass("blue");
  $("div").addClass("important");
  $('#snafu').removeClass('highlight');
});
```

I've also look at `document.stylesheets` and the seemingly archaic and browser-specific:

```
  document.styleSheets[0].insertRule("p{font-size: 20px;}", 0)
```

But I can't find any reference to programatically generating:

```
  @media screen and (min-width:400px)
```

from javascript directly or in any form.

Comment: Just updating an existing `style` element's contents seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/vfLS3/

Comment: Do you mean adding a css media query rule?

Comment: @ExplosionPills That is perfect and a worthy 'answer'

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can just update an existing `<style>` element (or create one) `textContent` to contain the rule, which will make it effective in the given context.

```
document.querySelector('style').textContent +=
    "@media screen and (min-width:400px) { div { color: red; }}"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vfLS3/

Comment: `$('style').text("@media (min-width:400px) {div{ color:red; }}")`

Comment: @MuhammadUmer that would overwrite the entire contents of the style element rather than append to it

Comment: @MuhammadUmer `.append` does not append text content but rather an element.  If the argument is a string, jQuery will attempt to select the element and will choke on `@`

Comment: but it does add text also

Comment: but safer way to do it would be like this `$('p')[0].innerHTML='css';
`

Answer (score 7):

I use this way. This allows to update multiply styles in document

in HTML:

```
<style class="background_image_styles">
</style>
```

in JS

```
$(".background_image_styles").text("@media (min-width: 1200px) {.user_background_image{background-image: url('https://placehold.it/1200x300');}}");
```

Answer (score 2):

For general purpose use, you can append a style sheet to `document.head`. Then you can put any mods in there you want -- including media queries. Since it's the final style sheet in `document.head`, it overrides any prior CSS rules.

Vanilla JavaScript:

```js
    let style = document.getElementById('custom-styles');
    if (!style) {
      style = document.createElement('style');
      style.id = "custom-styles";
      document.head.appendChild(style);
    }
    style.innerHTML =
      "@media screen and (min-width:400px) {...}";
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this variant - appending to the end of the head section:

```js
$('<style/>', {
    text: '@media print { @page { margin: 10 20 20 10; } body { margin: 0.5cm; }}',
    appendTo: win.document.head
})
```