# Why does modify CSS Rule fails when a media query has updated it

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

```
<head>
    <style>
        .cdm-tb { width: 960px; height: 90px; }
    </style>

    <script>
        ChangeCssRule(".cdm-tb", "width", "468px");
        ChangeCssRule(".cdm-tb", "height", "60px");
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <img src='images/testimage.jpg' class='cdm-tb' alt='test' />

</body>
```

ChangeCssRule is a JS function that works.  But when I add a couple media queries to the .cdm-tb style, updating the CSS rules no longer works.

```
    <style>
        .cdm-tb { width: 960px; height: 90px; }
        @media(min-width: 728px) {.cdm-tb { width: 728px; height: 90px; } }
        @media(min-width: 960px) {.cdm-tb { width: 960px; height: 90px; } }
    </style>
```

Is there an order of execution concerning media queries I am not understanding?  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you make a test case? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I am not familiar with jsfiddle enough to do it.  Here is a test: http://www.pcbuilderplus.com/test/index.html  and http://www.pcbuilderplus.com/test/index2.html with the media queries added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to modify the existing media query values but I did find a work around here: [Generating CSS media queries with javascript or jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050926/generating-css-media-queries-with-javascript-or-jquery).  The work around was to just append a brand new media query on the end of the < STYLE> tag to override any previous settings that were applied:

```
document.querySelector('style').textContent += 
           "@media(min-width: 468px) {.cdm-tb { width: 468px; height: 60px; } }";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

</head>
<style>
body{background:#000000;}
.cdm-tb { width: 960px; height: 90px; }
@media screen (min-width: 728px)
{
.cdm-tb { width: 728px; height: 90px;}
}

@media screen (min-width: 960px)
{
.cdm-tb { width: 960px; height: 90px;}
}
</style>
<img src='images/testimage.jpg' class='cdm-tb' alt='test' />

</html>
```

you have to add meta tag view port for responsive design