# ng-repeat not working inside a textarea

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The `ng-repeat` is not working inside a textarea. Any idea why? As soon as I moeve it outside the textarea, it works.

```
<textarea>
    <style ng-repeat="entry in bgTakeoverSettings.breakPoints">
      @media all and ({{entry.range}}: {{entry.bp}}px){
            {{bgTakeoverSettings.containerElements}}{
              width: {{entry.width - bgTakeoverSettings.padding * 2}}px;
            }

        }
    </style>
</textarea>
```

Comment: A textarea tag may only contain text.

Comment: What if I want to display the source code for a generated code? If I place it out of the textarea, then the current page gets affected.

Answer (score 0):

The content of a `textarea` is just arbitrary text. Therefore for the browser your `ng-repeat` is just plain text, and not as an instruction which it needs to process.

It is still possible to generate mediaqueries by code as shown in this topic: [Generating CSS media queries with javascript or jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050926/generating-css-media-queries-with-javascript-or-jquery)