# jQuery Side Navigation on jquery media queries

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have Side Navigation action in jQuery:

```
$(function openSidebar()) {
   document.getElementById("sidebar").style.width = "250px";
   document.getElementById("wrapper").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}

function closeSidebar() {
   document.getElementById("sidebar").style.width = "0";
   document.getElementById("wrapper").style.marginLeft= "0";
}
```

I need to change width from 250px to 100% on mobile devices. How can I get it on jQuery?

Comment: Why do you use `document.getElementById` with jQuery?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050926/generating-css-media-queries-with-javascript-or-jquery

Comment: @PeterMader I just used the solution from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sidenav.asp
You may have another suggestion in return?

Comment: @FilipKolendo, with jQuery, you normally use `$(...)` and [selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) to find elements in the DOM. In your case, it would be `$('#sidebar').css('width', '250px')`. Check out the [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   if ($(window).width() < 768) {
       $(function openSidebar()) {
           document.getElementById("sidebar").style.width = "100%";
           document.getElementById("wrapper").style.marginLeft = "100%";
       }

       function closeSidebar() {
           document.getElementById("sidebar").style.width = "0";
           document.getElementById("wrapper").style.marginLeft = "0";
       }
   } else {
       $(function openSidebar()) {
           document.getElementById("sidebar").style.width = "250px";
           document.getElementById("wrapper").style.marginLeft = "250px";
       }

       function closeSidebar() {
           document.getElementById("sidebar").style.width = "0";
           document.getElementById("wrapper").style.marginLeft = "0";
       }
   }
```

Update:

```
       if ($(window).width() < 768) {
           var width = "100%";
           var marginLeft = "100%";
       } else {
           var width = "250px";
           var marginLeft = "250px";
       }

        function openSidebar() {
           $("#sidebar").width(width);
           $("#wrapper").css('margin-left', marginLeft );
       };
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work and highlights getElementById in two places

Comment: @FilipKolendo I added your function name.

Comment: It bugs me to no end when websites decide to arbitrarily assume some random width means you're on a mobile device.

Comment: Now it works with only 250px and marginLeft on #wrapper is 0px all the time :/

Comment: On mobile device it woks with 100% but on regular laptop margin left is still 0px

Comment: Try setting ("margin-left") = "250px" manually and log marginLeft to see its value

Comment: Unfortunately the same thing

Comment: What did marginLeft log?

Comment: @FilipKolendo see edit `  $("#wrapper").css('margin-left', marginLeft );`

Comment: Console.log(marginLeft)

Comment: It works! Thanks @AbdullahSeba  But I have one more question. Now I can see how 100% works on a mobile device only, is there a way to view this in a browser?

Comment: How do you mean? View the value of marginLeft?

Comment: I mean that on the smartphone sidebar has a width of 100% but in the browser chrome on the pc i do not see 100% width even if I reduce the window size below 700px.

Comment: @FilipKolendo wrap it in `$( window ).resize(function() {
//code here
});`

Comment: After wrapping it in `$( window ).resize(function() { //code here });` It does not work at all. Going back to the previous method I noticed that the preview in the browser works after reducing the window and refreshing the page.

Comment: @FilipKolendo Because it checks the size once at page load.